# Plot an eye diagram with a cmap 'hot'

Tags: python

I'd like to plot an eye diagram with a 'hot' colormap that becomes clearer not when the signal has high values, but when the signal is dense at an instant in time, see picture below.

[image]

Here is what I've already done:

```
 def prbs_generation(size=15, oversampling_factor=100, bitrate=50, Fc=18.75, snr=20, plot=True, save=False):

  print("Generation of the PRBS ...")
  bit = list()
  start = 1
  lfsr = start
  i = 1

  while True:
      fb = ((lfsr >> (size-1)) ^ (lfsr >> (size-2)) & 1)
      lfsr = ((lfsr << 1) + fb) & (2 ** size - 1)
      bit.append(fb)
      if lfsr == start:

          break
      i = i + 1

  bit = [float(i) for i in bit]
  bit = np.array(bit)
  t = np.arange(0, len(bit)) * (1000 / bitrate)

  # "Continuous" signal
  g = np.ones(oversampling_factor)
  bit_oversampled = np.zeros(len(bit) * oversampling_factor)
  bit_oversampled[::oversampling_factor] = bit
  bit_oversampled = signal.lfilter(g,1, bit_oversampled)
  t_oversampled = np.arange(0, len(bit_oversampled)) * (1000 / (bitrate * oversampling_factor))

   # Filter the signal
  Fs = 1000 / t_oversampled[1]
  Wn = Fc / (Fs / 2)  # Cutoff frequency
  b, a = signal.bessel(4, Wn, btype='low', norm='mag')

  # Filter the signal
  w, h = signal.freqz(b, a, fs=Fs)
  bit_oversampled_filtered = signal.lfilter(b, a, bit_oversampled)

  # Add noise
  bit_filtered_noisy = add_noise(bit_oversampled_filtered, snr)

  if plot:
      # Eye diagram
      plotEyeDiagram_new(t_oversampled, bit_filtered_noisy, title='Eye diagram data generated', TSymb=20)
```

With  `plotEyeDiagram` :

```
def plotEyeDiagram_new(X, Y, title, TSymb, samples=100000, plot=True, save=False):

  NbSamples = len(Y)
  OldSamplingRate = 1000 * (NbSamples - 1) / (X[-1] - X[0])
  NewSamplingRate = OldSamplingRate + 0.03
  nbSamples2 = round((NbSamples - 1) * NewSamplingRate / OldSamplingRate + 1)
  Y2, X2 = signal.resample(Y, nbSamples2, X)

  dataEyeX = np.divmod(X2, 2 * TSymb)
  dataEyeX = dataEyeX[1]

  if plot:
      EyeFig = plt.figure()
      plt.scatter(dataEyeX[:samples], Y2[:samples], cmap='hot', s=3)
      plt.title(title, fontweight="bold")
      plt.xlabel("Time (ps)")
      plt.ylabel("Magnitude (A.U)")
      plt.grid()
      plt.tight_layout()

      if save:
          plt.savefig(title + ".png")

  return dataEyeX[:samples]
```

And `add_noise()` :

```
def add_noise(data, snr):
    signal_power = np.sum(data**2)/len(data)
    noise_power = signal_power/(10**(snr/10))
    noise = np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(noise_power), len(data))
    noisy_data = data + noise

    return noisy_data
```

Here an example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    prbs_generation(oversampling_factor=100, snr=20, Fc=18.75, plot=True)
    plt.show()
```

I get this king of figure when I filter and add noise :
[image]

Do you have any idea how to do it?
Let me know if I am not clear! ;)

Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't run (missing import and variable definition). Once fixed, it doesn't produce the eye diagram but just two straight lines.

Comment: Sorry @Hilmar. Changes has been made. Everything works now ! ;)